# Вылетает Android приложение на моменте подключения к БД

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Если вкратце, то в приложение происходит подключение к базе данных(SQLite), и считывание из неё информации.

Проблема в том, что на эмуляторе все работает как надо, приложение полностью функционирует. А вот при запуске приложения на устройстве оно вылетает.

**Почему на эмуляторе все работает как надо,а на устройстве происходит вылет?**

Приложение вылетает на этих строчках кода:

1. либо тут:

   ```
   mDatabaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this, "mydatabase.db", null, 1);
   mSqLiteDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   ```
2. либо, если вместо тех строчек использовать `mSqLiteDatabase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("mydatabase.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null)`, тут:

   ```
   Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.query(DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{
           DataBaseHelper.NAME,
           DataBaseHelper.NUMBER},
           null,null,null,null,null);
   ```

Выявлено опытным путем.

StackTrace при втором варианте(создание `cursor` происходит на 30 строчке в `StartActivity`):

```
    Process: ru.startandroid.begin, PID: 12643
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.startandroid.begin/ru.startandroid.begin.StartActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: database1 (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT name, number FROM database1
    #################################################################
    Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
    Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
    (no such table: database1 (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT name, number FROM database1)
    #################################################################
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3184)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:210)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1704)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: database1 (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT name, number FROM database1
    #################################################################
    Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
    Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
    (no such table: database1 (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT name, number FROM database1)
    #################################################################
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1093)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:670)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1454)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1301)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1172)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1340)
    at ru.startandroid.begin.StartActivity.onCreate(StartActivity.java:30)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6575)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3137)
    ... 10 more
```

Полное создание БД

```
package ru.startandroid.begin;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // имя базы данных
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase.db";
    // версия базы данных
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    //имя таблицы
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "database1";
    // название столбцов
    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String NUMBER = "number";
    //скрипт создания
    private static final String SCRIPT = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + NAME + " text no null, "
        + NUMBER + " long, " + " (Field1 VARCHAR, Field2 VARCHAR;)";

    DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    ////конструктор БД
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String name,
                            SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String name,
                            SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version,
                            DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        super(context, name, factory, version, errorHandler);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SCRIPT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Удаляем старую таблицу и создаём новую
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF IT EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        // Создаём новую таблицу
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

и полный код с Cursor

```
package ru.startandroid.begin;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.StringBuilderPrinter;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class StartActivity extends ListActivity {
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private DataBaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mSqLiteDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //подключаемся к БД!!!!!
        //mDatabaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this, "mydatabase.db", null, 1);
        //mSqLiteDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        mSqLiteDatabase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("mydatabase.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        ///////////////////////////////////// List
        Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.query(DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
            DataBaseHelper.NAME,
            DataBaseHelper.NUMBER},
            null,null,null,null,null);
        //cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
}
```

Comment: Сходу можно предположить около 48 причин. К сожалению в комментарий все они не влезут и вам надо приложить stackTrace ошибки и точную строку её возникновения для сокращения списка возможных причин

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Похоже, что у вас не создаётся база/таблица в ней. Т.е. вы обращаетесь к БД/таблице до того как её создадите/наполните данными. Покажите как вы создаёте таблицу и где вызываете этот метод.

Comment: Данные добавлены

Comment: Может быть у вас что-то с версиями на девайсе. Попробуйте данные приложения почистить. А может что-то с разрешениями на чтение/запись. Посмотрите есть ли они в манифесте. Также уточните на каких версиях ОС запускаете - на 6 андроиде разрешенния немного иначе работают

Comment: Андройд 5.1.1. Полностью переустановил приложение.

Нет я не нашел в манифесте ни одного разрешения, подскажите как должно называться то, которое мне нужно. Никак не могу найти описание каждого из них.

Comment: так же заметил что запись в БД происходит без вылета `mSqLiteDatabase.insert(DataBaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE,null,values);`

но если до него написать ту строку с Cursor, то произойдет вылет.

Comment: Т.е. данные записываются, и потом возвращаются? Может, вам надо наполнить так БД при её создании?

Comment: Нет, заполнение при создание не помогает. Ладно, спасибо большое за помощь. Наверное самое лучшее решение на данном этапе, это просто все написать заново, ведь все равно в проекте почти ничего нет, и рабочие варианты я нашел, буду ориентироваться на них)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В строке:

```
private static final String SCRIPT = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
    + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
    + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + NAME + " text no null, "
    + NUMBER + " long, " + " (Field1 VARCHAR, Field2 VARCHAR;)";
```

отсутствует имя колонки с ID.

**UPD** Благодаря [более внимательному Andrey Mihalev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/769698/177345) в соседнем ответе в итоге получаем такую строку:

```
private static final String SCRIPT = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
    + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
    + "_id integer primary key autoincrement, " + NAME + " text not null, "
    + NUMBER + " integer, " + " Field1 VARCHAR, Field2 VARCHAR)";
```

Answer (score 3):

У вас ошибки при создании БД. вот и ругается он, что нет нужной таблицы.
На эмуляторе скорее всего БД уже была создана ранее вот и нет в ней никаких проблем, проблемы будут когда вы поменяете переменную DATABASE_VERSION например на 2.
ваш код:

```
private static final String SCRIPT = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
    + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
    + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + NAME + " text no null, "
    + NUMBER + " long, " + " (Field1 VARCHAR, Field2 VARCHAR;)";
```

пропущено ID в **" integer primary key autoincrement, "**

```
"_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
```

в sql нет слова no, есть слово not поэтому текст **" text no null, "** исправляем на:

```
" text not null, "
```

последние поля зачем то помещены в скобку **" (Field1 VARCHAR, Field2 VARCHAR;)"**
первая скобка попросту не нужна! и удаляем точку с запятой в конце.

```
" Field1 VARCHAR, Field2 VARCHAR)"
```

итого получается, что ваша переменная SCRIPT будет выглядеть вот так:

```
private static final String SCRIPT = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
        + "_id integer primary key autoincrement, " + NAME + " text not null, "
        + NUMBER + " integer, " + " Field1 VARCHAR, Field2 VARCHAR)";
```

Comment: да, вот тоже позже заметил про "no null", даже не думал, что в одной строке можно допустить так много ошибок :( - но вы уже написали ответ. Еще  `long` нужно заменить на `INTEGER` - никакого типа *long* в SQLite нет

Comment: действительно просмотрел long. у меня нет прав оставлять комментарии к другим ответам, поэтому пришлось оставить свой.

Comment: Зато вы имеете полное право опубликовать ответ и получить заслуженную репутацию за внимательность :)

Answer (score 0):

А по-моему все гораздо проще.

Переименуйте поля - `name` и `number` - как минимум не совсем хорошие имена для полей. Кроме того, в Android является правилом имя первичного ключа `_ID` - лень искать ссылку.

Comment: _id (а не _ID) не правило, а суровая необходимость именования первичного ключа, если используются стандартные классы Android для работы с БД, вроде `Cursor`, и есть желание, чтобы они работали

Comment: В классе `BaseConstants` есть константа `_ID` которая содержит строку `_id`